# xpath challenge: How to merge multiple results into one result

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I use Ruby 1.9.3p385 and I use Nokogiri to parse XML files. Not quite sure which xpath version I use, but it does respond to v.1 syntax/functions, and not v.2 syntax.

I have this XML file:

```
<root_tag>
  <middle_tag>
    <item_tag>
      <headline_1>
        <tag_1>Product title 1</tag_1>
      </headline_1>
      <headline_2>
        <tag_2>Product attribute 1</tag_2>
      </headline_2>
    </item_tag>
    <item_tag>
      <headline_1>
        <tag_1>Product title 2</tag_1>
      </headline_1>
      <headline_2>
        <tag_2>Product attribute 2</tag_2>
      </headline_2>
    </item_tag>
  </middle_tag>
</root_tag>
```

I want to extract all the products, and for that I am using this code:

```
products = xml_file.xpath("/root_tag/middle_tag/item_tag/headline_1|/root_tag/middle_tag/item_tag/headline_2")

puts products.size # => 4
```

If you look at the output, using:

```
products.each_with_index do |product, i|
  puts "product #{i}:"
  puts product
end
```

you get this:

```
product 0:
<headline_1>
  <tag_1>Product title 1</tag_1>
</headline_1>
product 1:
<headline_2>
  <tag_2>Product attribute 1</tag_2>
</headline_2>
product 2:
<headline_1>
  <tag_1>Product title 2</tag_1>
</headline_1>
product 3:
<headline_2>
  <tag_2>Product attribute 2</tag_2>
</headline_2>
```

I need my code to join/merge all matches into the same result (so products.size should be 2). The final output should look something like this:

```
product 0:
<headline_1>
  <tag_1>Product title 1</tag_1>
</headline_1>
<headline_2>
  <tag_2>Product attribute 1</tag_2>
</headline_2>
product 1:
<headline_1>
  <tag_1>Product title 2</tag_1>
</headline_1>
<headline_2>
  <tag_2>Product attribute 2</tag_2>
</headline_2>
```

I have looked all over the internet, but all variations, e.g.:

```
products = xml_file.xpath("/root_tag/middle_tag/item_tag/*[self::headline_1|self::headline_2]")
```

all seems to output the same result.

Am I missing some important point in xpath, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Please edit your XML in a fashion which enables us to understand what your expected output should be like (eg., change "Product title" to different strings). Then, add expected output (without counting the results). Which XPath engine are you using, which XPath version does it support? It is not possible to answer your question the way it is right now without lots of guessing.

Comment: Hi @JensErat. Thanks very much for your reply. I am sorry if I left out important informations, and I have now updated my question after you instructions. Do I have it all covered now?

Comment: Question looks totally fine now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath only knows plain sequences, so there's nothing like subsequences. You will have to wrap each "product" into some XML element. Gladly we've already got such an element (`<item_tag/>`), so the code is rather simple:

```
products = doc.xpath("(//item_tag")
products.each_with_index do |product, i|
  puts "product #{i}:"
  product.children.each do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
```

Output is (probably needs some more formatting, but I'm not used to ruby and can't help you with that):

```
product 0:

<headline_1>
        <tag_1>Product title 1</tag_1>
      </headline_1>

<headline_2>
        <tag_2>Product attribute 1</tag_2>
      </headline_2>

product 1:

<headline_1>
        <tag_1>Product title 2</tag_1>
      </headline_1>

<headline_2>
        <tag_2>Product attribute 2</tag_2>
      </headline_2>
```

---

*To address all `<headline_n/>`-tags, you can also use `//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'headline')]` to make the code more flexible.*

Comment: That is perfect. The flexible xpath expression works for me out-of-the-box. coincidencially, one of the files in my test data has a path like this: _/item_tag_something/middle_tag/item_tag(headline_1|headline_2)_, which means that _item_tag_something_ returns TRUE and is therefore considered a product. But I will look through the xpath function library and see if I can get the expression to be a little less tolerant.